# Suppress records in grouped section between first two and last records in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

First, I am using Crystal Reports 2011.  I need to suppress records in a group that fall between the first two records and the last record.  In other words I only want to see record number 1 and 2 and the last record.  I can easily suppress records that are not the first two, but getting the last record to **not** be suppressed has me at a standstill.  I am creating a report where we want to only show the first, last and next-to-last time we purchased items.  Some items have been purchased many, many times.  I have the report grouped by part number, then all the dates we purchased the part (and other data) are in the group details.  I have tried using a running total count, where I simply suppress details that are not 1 or 2, but the last record count varies depending on how many times we have purchased the item, so I don't know what the last count number will be for each group to use it in the suppress formula.  I have also tried with declaring a variable and increment the variable for each record, but end up with the same problem as using running total count.  Anyone have a suggestion?

To clarify my question a little further, I am sorting the group by date, most recent date first.  So record count 1 is the last time we purchased and record count 2 is the next-to-last time we purchased.  So by using record count I can suppress records that are not 1 or 2.  The problem comes when trying to figure out how to not suppress the last record (which is the first time we purchased).  Below is a link to a pic of what my report looks like with nothing suppressed. For this part I would want to suppress all records except 1, 2 and 5.  But again, the last count number will change per part number depending on how may times we have purchased the part.

Help is greatly appreciated!!!!

[Report cropped image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0jqD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Using Crystal syntax you can test on OnLastRecord which returns true if you are on the last record or false if not. Simply suppress accordingly.

EDIT:

As pointed out by jmears, the above won't work for multiple groups of differing products.
Instead you can add a running total field to count each record within the group, reset on change of group.  Then suppress the details based on the running total not being 1 or 2 (for the first two records) and not equal to the total count of records for the group.
Here's an example suppression formula, where {#rt}  is the running total count of records.  It uses the Count function to return the total count for the group

> not({#rt} = 1 or {#rt} = 2 or {#rt} = Count ({fieldToCount}, {GroupField}))

Comment: Thank you for the advise, but OnLastRecord does not work for groups.  It only works on the last record of the entire report.  I need to show the last record of each group (as well as the first two records in each group).

Comment: Ahh, sorry. I'll take another look.

Comment: I've edited my answer to (hopefully) give you the correct solution.

Comment: Thanks Dan!!  I got it to work now.  Your info sent me in the right direction. For some reason it would not work exactly as you have it with "not", so I created a formula field called GC (for group count) to count the records in the group:  GC = Count ({fieldToCount}, {GroupField}) then I suppress records like this:  {#rt} <> {GC} and {#rt} <> 1 and {#rt} <> 2  This works great and I now have exactly what I need.  Thanks again for your help

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Strange you couldn't get it working eactly how I had it -